# x*y = k Constant Product Market Maker

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider, algorithm

**A short recap for Context**

In its basic form, a liquidity pool holds 2 tokens and creates a new market for that particular pair of tokens.

When a new pool is created, the FIRST liquidity provider is the one that sets the initial price of the assets in the pool.

The liquidity provider is incentivized to supply an equal value of both tokens in the pool.

When liquidity is supplied to a pool, the liquidity provider, LP, receives special tokens called LP tokens in proportion to how much liquidity they supplied to the pool.

When a trade, is facilitated by the pool, a 0.03% fee is proportionally distributed amongst all LP token holders.

If the liquidity provider wants to get their underlying liquidity back, plus any accrued fees, the must BURN their LP tokens.

Each token swap that the liquidity pool facilitates, results in a price adjustment according to a deterministic pricing algorithm.

This mechanism is also called, and Automated Market Maker.

Uniswap uses a Constant Product Market Maker algorithm to make sure that, the product of the quantities of the two supplied tokens always remains the same.

```
x * y = k
```

Because of this, the pool can ALWAYS provide liquidity no matter how large a trade/swap is.

The main take away here is that, the ratio of the tokens in the pool dictates the price.

Example:

Someone buys ETH from a DAI/ETH pool, they REDUCE the supply of ETH and ADD the supply of DAI.

This results in an INCREASE in the price of ETH and a DECREASE in the price of DAI.

How much the price moves depends on the SIZE of the TRADE in PROPORTION to the SIZE of the POOL.

The BIGGER the POOL relative to a TRADE, the LESSER the PRICE IMPACT and the LESSER SLIPPAGE.

The SMALLER the POOL relative to a TRADE, the GREATER the PRICE IMPACT and the GREATER SLIPPAGE.

I have put together a spreadsheet that demonstrates this with a double line chart.

**The** [Example SpreadSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SfQx2n4WTjJ8t0ZyWvVZR51uDZwT4dKRaXgRx0bGAUE/edit?usp=sharing)

**My question is, can anyone provide an example that demonstrates the price impact over a few transactions in Excel when the token X is pegged to the dollar eg. USDC? I just can't figure out a way to create an Excel version of it to really grasp what's going on. There's not much online that really dives into this concept as far as visualizing it in a simple way.**

Comment: It should be the same, usually the peg is maintained off the exchanges. For a third party the USDC in the pair will appear cheaper than its nominal value, and the trading and arbitrage opportunities will make it settle to the expected value in the end.